# Python3: Calculating complex exponents and logarithms

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

`math.exp()` doesn't work for complex numbers:

```
>>> math.exp (math.pi*1j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

This doesn't hurt me much, as `**` works as intended:

```
>>> math.e ** (math.pi*1j)
(-1+1.2246467991473532e-16j)
```

Now the problem is with logarithms. `math.log` doesn't work for negative numbers:

```
>>> math.log(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

(Expected result: `(0+3.141592653589793j)`)

**How can I calculate a logarithm in python whose result is complex?**
(Preferably without implementing it myself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The math documentation explicitly says that it does not support complex numbers. If you want a library in python that does, you should use [cmath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) instead.

Cmath stands for Complex Math.

cmath has most of the same interface as math, so for your example you could just do the following:

```
import cmath

cmath.log(-1)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. RTFM for me. I should have read the first paragraph of the documentation. Will accept as soon as cooldown is over.

Comment: @Hyperboreus No worries, it happens to the best of us.