# Is the expression math.sqrt() necessary?

Tags: python, math

I just started fooling around with python today; I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. Below is a little program I wrote to display primes, which seems to be working fine and pretty quickly:

```
import math
N = input('List primes up to: ')
N = int(N)
for i in range(3,N,2):
    for d in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))):
        if i%d==0:
            break
else :
    print(str(i))
```

The `sqrt()` function didn't work unless I kept in both the `math.sqrt()` part and the `import math` part. Also when I was typing stuff in the shell, it only worked if I used `math.sqrt()` instead of `sqrt()`.

So...long winded question for simple thing: is there some kind of `#include <math.h>`-esque line I can use, for the shell and the program file (though maybe different lines for each one) so I can avoid typing in the '`math.`' part every time I want to use functions from the math module? (it's a module, right?) (Because I swear I've read programs somewhere hat use `sqrt()` instead of `math.sqrt()`. But maybe not.)

Comment: The rule of thumb to use is "the only variables that are defined are the ones that *you* have defined". The good thing about this is that you can immediately tell what is a valid name -- an `import` statement only defines one variable. If you want to make it local, you can do `sqrt = math.sqrt`.

Comment: You could also just write `int(i ** .5)`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is sqrt() defined to be i**.5 or is it better/worse?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: You're not actually suggesting that 2x == x^2 are you?

Comment: @OllieB What are you talking about? i **.5 is i to the power of on half, which is sqrt(i).

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread the line with only one *

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 This is correct for real numbers. See my own stupid question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284623/python3-calculating-complex-exponents-and-logarithms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can import a function directly like this:

```
from math import sqrt
# elsewhere
sqrt(n)
```

You can even import everything from the module:

```
from math import *
```

In that way you won't have to use the module prefix and say `math.sqrt`. However, it's recommended that you do it, to avoid possible name clashes in case two modules define a function with the same name (something that happens quite often in practice). In short, this is the preferred way:

```
import math
# elsewhere
math.sqrt(n)
```

Comment: To clarify why you should leave it as math.sqrt(n), if you don't do that, there is a chance that another module will implement a function also named sqrt(n). There will be a namespace collision and you may end up using the other modules sqrt. It may do this extremely inefficiently, or incorrectly, or just crash your system because that's how that developer decided to make it. So you should stick with full module names for any long-living code that may be manipulated by another developer in the future.

Comment: The `math` module is the *only* one I import with `from math import *` just because it's so convenient. All others use one of the other two options.

Comment: There's even an obscure reason to prefer `from math import sqrt` over `math.sqrt`; while the latter indicates where you took the name from, the former needs a dictironary lookup less. As long as you don't use the wildcard, searching will still find the import line, so I don't mind the specific import.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from math import sqrt
```

or, if you want all of the names in the `math` module:

```
from math import *
```

Using either of the two methods will now allow you to just do `sqrt(n)` instead of `math.sqrt(n)`.

Note however that the second method will import EVERY name in the `math` module.  It is usually better to just import what you need (like in the first example).

Comment: What are the downsides to importing everything? Does it significantly affect speed on a higher level?

Comment: @Thornshadow17432, it's to prevent name collisions. Suppose you do `from math import *` then on the next line `from mylogger import *` - what do you think `log` will be defined as?

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 - Also, it makes for cleaner, more concise code.  An analogy could be hanging a picture.  To hang a picture, I use a hammer and a nail.  Not a hammer, a nail, a screwdriver, a saw, pliers, and a ratchet set.  See the difference? :)

Comment: OK--so general rule, just use math.sqrt(). What is the period / dot thingy between math and sqrt() usually referred to as?

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 - I actually don't know if it has a special name...I've never called it anything different than "dot".